# Node JS array of Promises still in <pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'd like to do some check on a file with Promises before processing it.

As I'm using Node JS, I'd like to do all the verification asynchronously since they're all independant.

However, I'd like to print all the errors at once (if they are some) for debugging purpose. So I need to wait for all the operation to be done before doing anything else. So I'm using the async/wait keywords.

Here's my code :

```
async function isValid(file) {
         try {
            const check = [
                check1(file),
                check2(file),
                check3(file),
                check4(file),
                check5(file)
            ]

            let results = check.map(async checking => (await checking))
            console.log((await results));

         } catch(e) {
             console.log(e)
         }

}
```

The thing is, what's outputted by the console.log is the following:

```
[
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
```

What I expected to get was the result of the checks() function, but they're still pending despite the await keywords present multiple times.

Do you know what's wrong I'm doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `async` and `map` will not do what you want.  You still need to `Promise.all` what `map` returns.

Comment: If you really want to print all errors you should use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, they gave me a good indication :) I used another method for the current context, but will take note of theses commands for other uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `Promise.all` here. You don't actually have to do your `.map` logic to invoke each individual function and `await` it. As long as `check(<file>)` returns a `Promise`, just call `Promise.all` on them.

Example:

```js
async function isValid(file) {
  try {
    const check = [
      check1(file),
      check2(file),
      check3(file),
      check4(file),
      check5(file)
    ]

    const results = await Promise.all(check);
    console.log('results', results);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: OP wants to `I'd like to print all the errors at once`, your solution shows only first error

Comment: Thanks, this solution has helped me actually. I handled manually the errors since my Promise are dict under the form `{ success: false, reason: 'bad_file_type' }`. I'm not sure it's a good practice though